# HTML form redirect not working

Tags: html, forms, redirect

I'm doing some **troubleshooting** for someones website, they have an order form that isnt redirecting the user to another page after the form is submitted, they're getting a

> "The requested URL /pubs/mains/publishingCONF.html was not found on
>   this server."

error when they form attempts to redirect.

Heres the redirect code, just wondering if its valid to use "value" as the redirect?

```
    <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="../pubs/mains/publishingCONF.html" />
```

[image]
"formrp.html" is the file with the above code snippet, located in'books'

[image]
"publishingCONF.html" is the redirect, located in 'pubs/main'

Comment: Yes absolutely, if the server side script which reads the posted form data correctly reads the redirect. My guess is that the file doesn't exist, or is not in the correct folder

Comment: already checked the file structure and it all aligns correctly.

Comment: You can use a PHP script: `header('location: http://example.com/pubs/mains/publishingCONF.html') //this can be anything...`

Comment: The error is that the file doesn't exist, so the form has no issues. The issue is with the location of the file, could you link a screenshot of the directory tree?

Comment: ok ive added images from Filezilla